# What is a balance of a chapter in a book?

Tags: word-meaning

> the exact strategy whereby this determination is made will be covered in the balance of this chapter.

If I understand this right, a balance is a section in a chapter, but I couldn't find this meaning in my dictionary.

Comment: Welcome! Here, *in the balance of this chapter* is just a (long) way of saying *in this chapter*. It does not have a more specific meaning, and could (should!) be left out.

Comment: @legatrix I don't believe that's quite right.  It specifically refers to the _remainder_ of the chapter after a specific point, which does add additional meaning (albeit not a _lot_ of additional meaning).  I've elaborated on that a bit in my answer.

Comment: @RyanM you could well be right there. I agree with you that this is a possible, and common, use of the phrase. However, I had a distinct intuition that this text came from the beginning of a chapter. If I'm wrong, happy to retract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly unusual (but not uncommon) use of "balance" to mean "remainder."  It means that the answer will be given in the part of the chapter after what was already discussed (likely after the point where this text appears, but it's a bit hard to tell without additional context).  It means the same as though they'd said "the rest of this chapter" or "the remainder of this chapter."

Via [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balance):

> something left over : **REMAINDER**
>
> *answers will be given in the balance of this chapter*
>
> — R. W. Murray